# What are the minimum required environment variables?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, exec

I am writing a shell.

With the `execvpe` system call, I can run a program and control its environment.  What are the minimum values I need to pass through here?

Alternatively, I understand that child processes should have a copy of their parent's environment, possibly with some values added.  While testing my shell, I am running it from within bash from within my terminal from within a window manager, etc etc.  What are the bare basics that I can assume are in my environment?  If I were to run my shell straight from a TTY (the "lowest level", as far as I understand), what can I expect?

Answer (score 2):

That’s a very broad question.  To a certain extent,
programs should be able to run with no environment at all.

- “X” display (i.e., GUI) programs need to know
  where they are supposed to display. 
  This information is usually provided
  through the `DISPLAY` environment variable,
  but can also be passed on the command line. 
  There are probably other environment variables that are essential
  (or nearly so) to “X” programs;
  it’s been a while since I’ve looked under that hood.
- Any program that needs to use special characteristics of your terminal
  needs the `TERM` environment variable. 
  “Special characteristics” means being able to set colors
  (as `ls` and `grep` can do, subject to options),
  move around the screen (like `vi` / `vim`),
  or even know the size of the screen (like `less`). 
  Note that size of the screen may also be available
  through `ROWS` and `COLUMNS`.
- Any program that needs to know the date and time
  *as perceived / understood by the user* needs to know the time zone (`TZ`) —
  although, if you’re willing to work with absolute (GMT / UTC),
  you don’t need this.

etc.

Answer (score 2):

The *minimum* that you need is a working `PATH` variable.  Any extras beyond that depend on what programs you want to execute.

[POSIX has a list of commonly-used environment variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html), very few programs use more than a few of those.

Generally if you're using **execvp***, you're not giving full pathnames for the executables.  It makes your programs much simpler, you do not have to provide a full pathname for each executable, as is needed by the plain **execv**.  [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) describes these functions as

```
 int execv(const char *path, char *const argv[]);
 int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);
```

and (referring to the parameters of the various **exec*** functions):

> The argument *path* points to a pathname that identifies the new process image file.
>
> The argument *file* is used to construct a pathname that identifies the new process image file. If the *file* argument contains a slash character, the *file* argument shall be used as the pathname for this file. Otherwise, the path prefix for this file is obtained by a search of the directories passed as the environment variable **`PATH`** (see XBD Environment Variables). If this environment variable is not present, the results of the search are ***implementation-defined***.

and (remember that *"file"* is referring to `execvp` rather than `execv`, so the `environ` variable applies to the search using **`PATH`** for the *"file"* parameter):

> For those forms not containing an envp pointer (**`execl()`**, **`execv()`**, **`execlp()`**, and **`execvp()`**), the environment for the new process image shall be taken from the external variable *environ* in the calling process.

So... you could technically remove the entire **`PATH`** variable, but the result would be ***implementation-defined***.

Comment: You don't _even_ need PATH.

Comment: Generally if you're using `execvp*`, you're not giving full pathnames for the executables.

Comment: You might be building an embedded device, and all your commands are specified by full path. I've also seen embedded devices (I think Android is an example) that work fine without a PATH variable. I assume that the shell uses a default path of its own. But yeah, in a general-purpose Unix system, running without $PATH (and $HOME while we're at it) isn't very useful.

Answer (score 1):

The *minimum* neccessary environment is empty.  You don't *need* anything.

e.g.

```
$ env -i env
$
```

We can see that `env -i` has created a blank environment.

We can take this further:

```
$ env -i /bin/bash
sweh@server:/home/sweh$ env
LS_COLORS=
PWD=/home/sweh
SHLVL=1
_=/usr/bin/env
```

We can see that `bash` has set a few variables, but nothing was inherited.

Now such an environment may break some things; e.g. a missing `TERM` variable means that `vi` or `less` *may* not work properly

```
$ less foo 
WARNING: terminal is not fully functional
foo  (press RETURN)
```

So, really, you need to determine what programs you expect to run inside the environment and what their needs are.